# Unnesting Lists Inside of Dataframes

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have two lists that are the result of a for loop:

pid list <- [List of IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5cdU.png)

violations <- [List of Violations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opbMy.png)

Now, when I run the following:

```
df <- cbind(pid_list, violations) %>%
    as.data.frame()
head(df)
```

I end up with a dataframe with a column on the left and a list in the right that looks like this: [Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLyw8.png)

What I would like the result to be is:

| pid_list | violations |
| --- | --- |
| -6928390558574835 |  |
| -6141623232242576 |  |
| -4584655687749366 |  |
| -2856811727809710 | 381 |
| -2856811727809710 | 382 |
| -2856811727809710 | 383 |
| -2856811727809710 | 384 |
| -2856811727809710 | 385 |
| -2856811727809710 | 386 |
| -2856811727809710 | 387 |
| -2856811727809710 | 388 |
| -1860498996583344 |  |

So I can join it back to a previous table that I have and remove the rows with `NULL` violations.

I've tried some `unlist()` and `purrr()` methods without much success -- does anyone here have any recommendations?

Comment: @akrun - What's `dput` ? I'll be sure to use it going forward!

Comment: use `dput(head(Current_Results_table))` copy the output you obtain and paste it in your question. It enables you share data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could loop over the `violations` list, if the `upper` element is `NULL`, convert it to `NA`, extract the `upper` element, construct the data.frame by replicating the 'pid_list' based on the `lengths` of the `violations` list in `base R`

```
violations <- lapply(violations, \(x) {if(is.null(x$upper) || 
    length(x$upper) == 0) {x$upper <- NA}
        x$upper})
pid_list[lengths(pid_list) == 0| is.null(pid_list)] <- NA
data.frame(pid_list = unlist(pid_list)[rep(seq_along(pid_list), 
      lengths(violations))], 
     violations = unlist(violations))
```

-output

```
               pid_list violations
1  -6928390558574835712         NA
2  -6141623232242576384         NA
3  -4584655687749366272         NA
4  -2856811727809710592        381
5  -2856811727809710592        382
6  -2856811727809710592        383
7  -2856811727809710592        384
8  -2856811727809710592        385
9  -2856811727809710592        386
10 -2856811727809710592        387
11 -2856811727809710592        388
12 -1860498996583344128         NA
13  1345936609258173440         NA
```

#### data

```
violations <-  list(list(upper = integer(0)), list(upper = integer(0)), list( upper = integer(0)), list(upper = 381:388), list(upper = integer(0)), list(upper = integer(0))) 
pid_list <- list("-6928390558574835712", "-6141623232242576384", "-4584655687749366272", "-2856811727809710592", "-1860498996583344128", "1345936609258173440")
```

Comment: That's a great idea! 

I got an error when attempting the solution - `Error in x$upper : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. 

I tried replacing every `x$upper` with `x[[upper]]` for which the error was `object 'upper' not found`.

I then tried `x[['upper']]`  for which the error was `subscript out of bounds`. 

Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: @AndrewGetz I assumed you have a `list` inside each list from the image.  If you have named vector.  you need `x['upper']`

Comment: @AndrewGetz can you show `dput(head(violations))` i.e. your original violations list

Comment: That worked!  So I think the unlist is working, but the join is now giving me an error of `Error in data.frame(pid_list = unlist(pid_list)[lengths(violations)],  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 13, 8`. 13 is the total length of the `pid_list` and 8 is the length of our newly functioning unlist.

Comment: Running `dput` now.

Comment: `dput` results:

list(list(upper = integer(0)), list(upper = integer(0)), list(
    upper = integer(0)), list(upper = 381:388), list(upper = integer(0)), 
    list(upper = integer(0)))

Comment: @AndrewGetz may be you were using the old code which I updated.  Refresh the page and try the code

Comment: @AndrewGetz I tried your input for violations with modified pid_list as the example I created had only 3 elements.  It is working for me

Comment: When I use your data it works on my end too. With my input lists, coming out of the for loop they are the same length which join properly. It's this later step that's proving to be a challenge as I need each pid associated with each violation. Each violation is a day number, so I'll join it back to a row_numbered dim-date table to get on which days these violations occurred for each pid.

Comment: @AndrewGetz do you have `NULL` elements in pid_list`

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I really appreciate your help as well, this is my first question on Stackoverflow after using it as a resource for so long to teach myself.

Comment: I do not -- here is the `dput` for pid_list: list("-6928390558574835712", "-6141623232242576384", "-4584655687749366272", 
    "-2856811727809710592", "-1860498996583344128", "1345936609258173440")

Comment: @AndrewGetz that examples are working for me

Comment: I'm still getting the differing number of rows error -- is there any additional information I can provide that would be helpful?

Comment: @AndrewGetz may be in your original data, there may be some NULL cases or `integer(0)` in pid_list.  Try `pid_list[lengths(pid_list) == 0| is.null(pid_list)] <- NA`

Comment: Unfortunately, that returns the same error. Hmmmm....

Comment: @AndrewGetz As I said earlier, your examples are working fine for me.  Maybe you can try on a small subset of your data that doesn't work and get the dput of that subset

Comment: I got it working, when I changed `x$upper` to `x['upper']` to solve the atomic issue it must have been from another error. Removed them, and its working now. One last question, how would I call upon it later?

Comment: If I change anything in that cell including the `violations <-` assignment -- it breaks it.

Comment: @AndrewGetz  that implies some of your list elements have named vectors and some have list elements

Comment: I don't know how I managed that; but , I got it working -- thank you!